# Complex number second degree function

Tags: functions

This is my first question posted here, but I came across this when following an example in my textbook.

It's part of factorizing an equation to enable a Laplace Transformation.

$s^2 + 4s + 5 \implies D = -4$, so complex roots ($j = \sqrt{-1}$)

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{D}}{2a} $$
$$ \frac{-4 \pm 2j}{2} \implies (-2 + j)\text{ and }(-2 - j) $$

But if I then multiply: $(s - 2 + j)(s - 2 - j)$, I get $s^2 - 4s + 5$

So I was wondering why it's $-b$ instead of $b$, this yields $4s$.
I googled it but couldn't find anything on the formula changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did it incorrectly. $s - (-2 + j) = s + 2 -j$ and $s - (-2-j) = s + 2 + j.$